# Can't connect to a remote MySQL during installation, drupal uses unix_socket instead of host?

Tags: installation, database

I'm installing a drupal site on a cloud, which has a remote database cloud service.

But I found that drupal seems ignore the `host` I give and use `unix_socket` to connect the remote database.

Here is the **Set up database** screen during installation. I'm sure database name, username and password are correct. I have try ip address and domain name in the `host` field. The `socket` field leaves **empty**.

[image]

And I got:

> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Invalid argument.

I'm not familiar with PHP and mysql, I don't know a better way to find out what *Invalid argument* is. I So I do some `grep` and add some `print_r()` in `[drupaldir]/includes/database/database.inc`:

```
$driver_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
print_r($dsn);print_r($username);print_r($password);print_r($driver_options);
// Call PDO::__construct and PDO::setAttribute.
parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options);
```

This is what I got (add a few line break, and replace the real name and password):

```
mysql:unix_socket=;dbname=demo_db
demo_username
demo_password
Array ( [1000] => 1 [20] => 1 [3] => 2 )
```

Is this mean, Drupal installation ignores the `host` what ever I give and just use `unix_socket` even it's empty?

Comment: You should file an issue on drupal.org for this. When you 'hack core', you live dangerous, because you will have to reapply this patch every time you update drupal core - and will probably forget eventually. The better way to fix this in your case is, to fix the entry in your settings.php file. It is located in sites/default or sites/example.com. And to make it won't happen to the next person, file an issue.

Comment: Please post answers as an answers, not as edits to a question. Answer still available in revision history, should you want to copy-paste it from there.

Comment: It just looks like `unix_socket=;` is an empty string and not used in that output. Make sure your remote firewall accepts connections on the mysql port from your host/ip address.

Comment: @DavidThomas See [this revision](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/99372/2) for OPs solution.

Comment: David,I am having a problem connecting to a remote MySQL server.  Logging on to the remote MySQL from the Drupal box directly works but Drupal can't connect to the db.  setting.php looks good.  I am hesitant to change core.  What additional settings in settings.php would circumvent this problem?  The Drupal box doesn't have mysql.sock installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have located this issue. includes/database/mysql/database.inc, line 32:

```
// The DSN should use either a socket or a host/port.
if (isset($connection_options['unix_socket'])) {// will be TRUE if unix_socket is ''
  $dsn = 'mysql:unix_socket=' . $connection_options['unix_socket'];
}
else {
  // Default to TCP connection on port 3306.
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $connection_options['host'] . ';port=' . (empty($connection_options['port']) ? 3306 : $connection_options['port']);
}
```

`$connection_options['unix_socket']` will be an empty string if we leave it empty on the page. So this test will be `TRUE`. Replace `isset` with `!empty` solve this issue:)